# Regex: How can I make this code shorter? (Accented characters)

Tags: regex, regex-negation

So I have this regex code which looks for all accented characters but was wondering if there was a way to shorten it.

```
[^ÀàÁáÂâÃãÄäÅåÇçÈèÉéÊêËëÌìÍíÎîÏïÑñÒòÓóÔôÕõÖöÙùÚúÛûÜüÿ]
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you consider an accented character? Does Æ count? Or Ǣ? I don't know if I'd count Ø; a quick Google search seems to indicate it's considered a distinct letter rather than a letter with an accent.

Comment: ".. which looks for all accented characters" – well actually it looks for the inverse. Are you looking for `[^[:ascii:]]+`?

Comment: Removed the O character with the line going through it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex: `[^\u00C0-\u017F]`

You can use `\u...` in regex for specifying unicode character by its code.
Hyphen is used for specifying range of characters.
`^` is used for excluding that range.
So in this regex we are excluding all characters which are between \u00C0 and \u017F characters.

*Test:*

```js
var str = "ÀàÁháÂâeÃãÄläÅlåÇçÈèÉoéÊêËëwÌìÍoíÎîrÏïÑñlÒòÓóÔôdÕõÖöØøÙùÚúÛûÜüÿ";
var result = str.match(/[^\u00C0-\u017F]/g);
document.write(result.join(' '));
```

Comment: Wait--how do you get that code snippet runner to appear?

Comment: Hmm, it kind of works. Can you explain the code a bit. For example, what does the \u mean and what does the hyphen do in the middle? Does it state to look for everything in between the left and right because I thought if you had a hyphen then it represented a literal hyphen to search for.

Comment: Thanks so much for clearing that up! Here's my issue. When I have `([^a-zA-Z]|[^\u00C0-\u017F]|$)` it doesn't work but when I have `([^a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F]|$)` it works flawlessly. Any thoughts?

Comment: @NRitH Well, I wouldn't worry about how. It only prints "helloworld" right now. Pretty sure that isn't what that code does.

Comment: @sdrtyrty rtyuty You can check the difference between that regexes using regexper: [regex1](https://regexper.com/#(%5B%5Ea-zA-Z%5D%7C%5B%5E%5Cu00C0-%5Cu017F%5D%7C%24)) and [regex2](https://regexper.com/#(%5B%5Ea-zA-Z%5Cu00C0-%5Cu017F%5D%7C%24)). Hope it'll help you.

Comment: @sdrtyrty rtyuty If it will not help you to understand why it behaves so, ask away. I'll be pleased to help.

Comment: Thanks for the links! They help to visualize the code but I guess my head just can't quite wrap around the different between NOT a OR not b [vs] NOT a, b.... but I'll just use the code that works.

Comment: @sdrtyrty rtyuty If you are excluding two sets of characters merging them with `|` it will exclude only intersection of these groups.
You can imagine this this way `If character is not in set1 or character is not in set2 then it corresponds to expectations`

Comment: I think I get it now. Don't use multiple negations separated by an OR symbol as it will look for both to be negated. Else it will show up as not found. Tough to put so much negativity into words lol but hopefully I get it now. Also thanks for the unicode bit. It helped a lot.

Comment: This is totally wrong. Stuff like "÷" is in that range, while combining diacritics and plenty of precomposed characters like "ȁ" won't be caught.